# Filter XsltListViewWebPart using Choice Filter

Tags: filter, dropdown

I have put choice filter for filtering records in XsltListViewWebPart.

but choice filter opens a popup box. and select one(it display like radio buttions with items) of item from it.

I don't want use this functionality..

I need just simple dropdownlist for filtering items.

Like this..

[image]

How to do this?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to get dropdowns instead of popups is to (in any way) force the URL to contain the query string **Filter=1**.

```
/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?Filter=1
```